# Number of solutions of given equation

Tags: calculus

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEHdn.png)
[I am getting options C. I find solutions after drawing graph of e^x and x^2

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be seen from inspection of the plots of these two functions.  The equation $e^x = x^2$ has two real solutions (in [Cartesian Quadrants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)) I and II) and the equation $e^x = x^3$ has one solution (in Quadrant I).  The correct answer is (c).  (If you would like to prove the existence of solutions in each of these quadrants, this can be done using the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).)

Answer (score 0):

The equation $e^x=x^2$ has one solution, which you can see when you plot the two functions $f(x)=e^x$ and $f(x)=x^2$. The equation $e^x=x^3$ has two solutions, which you can see when you plot them as well.

I would guess this question wants you to look at the plots because solving these equations requires the use of the special function, i.e. the W Lambert function.

So, the answer is A.

Comment: After plotting graph i found that e^x and X^2 intersect at two point